# Buying lenses from Japan on eBay? Good or bad?

Tags: lens, canon, ebay

I have been looking into Canon's older 28-80mm USM metal mount lens. I have heard that it is a very good lens for the money, but when I looked for it on eBay, the only places that seem to sell it are from Japan.

Here is an example of the lens I am talking about:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/Excellent-CANON-EF-28-80mm-F3-5-5-6-USM-/121642460981?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item1c5274a735

Even though the seller has 100% positive feedback, are there things I need to consider before buying? I have noticed that a lot of lenses from Japan are noticeably cheaper than from USA sellers. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: What country are you located in?

Comment: The US Dollar is currently stronger against the Japanese Yen than has historically been the case in recent times. That is what is driving prices in the U.S. down: it takes fewer dollars to buy the same number of yen.

Comment: I am located in the United States. Thank you for the information. That makes more sense to me now. So I presume that if that is why prices are lower, than there isn't really an risk in buying from someone in japan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By buying from another country, you are effectively buying on the gray market (related: [Is there a drawback in buying an imported (gray market) lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4480/is-there-a-drawback-in-buying-an-imported-gray-market-lens)).  You will find it difficult to make use of a warranty or in some cases, even authorized repair shops will be hesitant to touch it.

You are also going to pay... what appears to be $27 for shopping in this referenced auction for a lens that is being sold for $50, for something that will end up closer to $80.

On the other hand, the used domestic market you will find it, well, much cheaper. The 28-80 Canon f/3.5-5.6 that you linked can be found at KEH in excellent condition for about $45 (the second edition of the lens is also in the same price range: [KEH search: Canon 28-80](https://www.keh.com/search/list?s=Canon+28-80))  The estimate for shipping on this lens can be found... for me, its $12.

This ends up with something that is less expensive overall, I'll get it sooner, from a known dealer (KEH is very good).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking generally, here are the problems I see with buying photographic equipment internationally:

- If the seller speaks a different language to you, there may well be problems communicating about problems or even simply about the basic item details/condition.
- You are importing an item - you may/will be liable to pay sales tax and customs duty as levied by your local customs service.
- If the item turns out to be faulty and you need to return it, you will incur potentially high, potentially non-refundable shipping costs, as well as probably not being able to recover the tax/duties that you've already paid.
- I guess there is a higher risk of something getting "lost in the post". You should be paying for a shipping service that includes international tracking with proof of delivery.
- Some manufacturers do not honour the warranty on an item intended for sale in a different geographic region. For example, the serial number may betray that this lens was intended for sale in Japan, not your own country.

Personally, I do not consider the risk of fraud or unscrupulous behaviour by a seller to be any higher internationally than domestically.

Answer (score -3):

A canon lens is a canon lens. They will honor a warranty and I’ve never had an issue with a dealer in the states working on it. Don’t listen to yahoo’s out there talking without having a lens from Japan. They are not talking from experience they are talking out their rear.

Comment: You will actually get some trouble as most companies do not honor warranty on a grey market item.

Comment: Many years ago I bought a grey-market Minolta camera and a couple of lenses, because Minolta came with an international warranty. Sure enough, I had to send it in for warranty service, and had no problems. The same can't be said for every manufacturer, and rules can also change over time. I didn't downvote, but my biggest problem with this answer is the exceptionally poor, undignified delivery, and the complete lack of references. Just one yahoo's, one-time experience.

Comment: Canon seems better than most manufacturers in terms of accepting gray market gear for service, with the caveat that they will often/likely charge you for the service if it's gray market, even if it's within the warranty period. [Canon's own website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/groups/gray-market) states in a big red box, "Customers should also be aware that Gray Market products MAY NOT be eligible for: X Coverage under a U.S. warranty; ..." Thus, obviously, _caveat emptor_.

Comment: But why the poor, arrogant, and dismissive response? I did downvote, on that basis alone.